# How to perform operation on all mp3s in a folder?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to speed up the tempo of all mp3 files in my `C:\MP3\AudioBooks\The Idea Factory` folder. I can do any individual file thusly, with success:

```
sox --show-progress "C:\MP3\AudioBooks\The Idea Factory\002.mp3" "C:\MP3\AudioBooks\The Idea Factory\speedy\002.mp3" tempo 1.3
```

But I'm getting lost in the cmd-line looping logic:

```
FOR %%I in ("C:\MP3\AudioBooks\The Idea Factory\*.mp3") DO (
   echo %%I
   echo %~pI
   echo %~nI
)
```

You can see I'm just doing echos for now, not sure how to change the output path based on the input path, and the 2nd and 3rd echo statements blow up anyway. 1st one works.

What's the simplest way to take a folder path input, loop through all mp3 files in there (no subfolders, just mp3s), and simply execute my sox command against each, with the output mp3 going into the `speedy` subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```bat
For %%I In ("C:\MP3\AudioBooks\The Idea Factory\*.mp3"
) Do sox --show-progress "%%I" "%%~dpIspeedy\%%~nxI" tempo 1.3
```

Comment: a few seconds before me... I suggest using `"%%~fI"` instead of `"%%I"`. Just to be sure to get the full qualified file name.

Comment: @Stephan, had the OP not used a fully qualified path for their source directory, I would have indeed used `%%~fI` but as they did, it seemed completely unnecessary